# verification by play protect

Tags: java, android

I have build an app which is running fine on my emulator but when I build a debug APK for my client for demo purpose it shows error "Blocked by play protect error"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyvEN.jpg)

Comment: that's security alert. just click on "install anyway"

Comment: Since the app is a debug build & probably hasn't been uploaded to Google Play, the Play Protect installed on the phone will flag it as it doesn't recognise the developer associated with that package name of the app. If it's for testing, you can safely click on `Install Anyway`.